# KendoUI pagination throws exception and doesn't show page information

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, pagination

I'm trying to get a KendoUI grid working with server side paging. So far I've managed to get the grid reading data from the remote datasource and correctly sending paging/filtering information to an MVC controller action

This is working fine, however, I don't see the paging controls for the grid at all.

I've tried adding `pageable: true` to the setup of the grid, and although this does display the pager control, it doesn't show any pages/totals and throws a JS **object does not support this property or method** when I try and change the page using the next/prev page buttons. The method it's looking for is 'slice' - I'm going to have a look at the non-minified kendo src but in the meantime I thought I'd post here

The action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult _Index(int? pageSize, int? skip, string filter = "")
{
    // Code that gets the data
    var data = ... (some Linq->Entities queries)
    var total = ... (total count of all the entities)

    return Json(new { total, data });
}
```

I'm correctly returning the total, and I've checked the JSON and it matches what I'm expecting (and what the grid should be expecting)

The grid setup is this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var grid = $("#itemList").kendoGrid({
        toolbar: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
        columns: ["Manufacturer", "Model", "Price", "Tags"],
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "catalogadmin/_index",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        filter: ""
                    }
                },
            },
            schema: {
                data: "data", // records are returned in the "data" field of the response
                total: "total" // total number of records is in the "total" field of the response
            },
            pageSize: 2,
            serverPaging: true
        },
        pageable: true
});
```

I set the pageSize to 2 to test paging (as I only have 4 items in the DB at the mo)

JSON is:

```
{"total":4,"data":[{"Id":6,"Manufacturer":"hello","Model":";lmqw;lemwqe","Price":4.00,"ShortDescription":"world","Tags":[],"Used":false}]}
```

I don't think that's the issue though - it seems like you need to set `pageable: true` to get paging working - but I don't think the paging even works with client side data, I'm just going to check now

Edit: I've checked and client-side paging doesn't work either. I get an 'Unable to get property toLowerCase of undefined or null reference' when trying to page. The pager looks like the server side page, no data, no page numbers, no totals.

I'm thinking Kendo isn't quite registered right - I've got the very latest version (just downloaded it now) but no cigar...

Comment: Could you edit the question and show the JSON that your service is returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted - not sure why but when I installed KendoUI using Teleriks 'convert to Kendo UI project' it registered both the `kendo.all.min.js` file and also the mvc/dataviz ones.

I removed the extra script references and it's all working now!